# What is the Space Complexity of Array.filter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, space-complexity

I just finished working on the Leetcode problem [Find All Duplicates in an Array](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-all-duplicates-in-an-array/) and have some questions about the space complexity of the problem. This problem specifically asks for O(1) space complexity. Below I have written four different ways to solve this problem, but I am unsure what the space complexity of each of these options are.

The four options I came up with were:

1. Create a results array and store duplicate numbers in that. Then return this array. I believe this is O(n) because I need the extra array.
2. Filter the nums array and store this in the nums variable. I am unsure if this is O(1) or O(n) as I am now generating a new array, but then replacing my original right away.
3. Filter the nums array and immediately return the new array.
4. Use a custom filterInPlace function to modify the size of the nums array. I believe this is O(1) but it is a bit of a hassle to need to write for a Leetcode problem.

I would appreciate some clarity on this. Thanks!

```
const findDuplicates = (nums) => {
  
  const swap = (i, j) => {
    [nums[i], nums[j]] = [nums[j], nums[i]];
  };
  
  let i = 0;
  let idx;
  const n = nums.length;
  
  while (i < n) {
    
    idx = nums[i] - 1;
    
    if (nums[i] !== nums[idx]) {
      swap(i, idx);
    } else {
      i += 1;
    }
  }
  
  // Option 1 - Use a results array to contain duplicates
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
    if (nums[i] !== i + 1) {
      result.push(nums[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;

  // Option 2 - Filter out duplicates and save in nums, then return nums
  nums = nums.filter((num, i) => num !== i + 1);
  return nums;

  // Option 3 - Return the new array returned from Array.filter
  return nums.filter((num, i) => num !== i + 1);

  // Option 4 - Write a filterInPlace function to modify array in place
  const filterInPlace = (array, condition) => {

    // The number of items that have been kept
    let j = 0;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
      if (condition(array[i], i)) {
        array[j] = array[i];
        j += 1;
      }
    }
   
    array.length = j;
    return array;
  }

  filterInPlace(nums, (num, i) => num !== i + 1);
  return nums;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The space is going to be `O(n)` for sure.
2. and 3.   Both are same , You can directly return it or Assign to new variable , then return it. Array.filter return a new array of required elements which is also `O(n)` space for the newly formed array .

4. This is `O(1)` because you just modify `nums` array